# how to use divider in html5?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone suggest how to use a dividers positioned at the center of a page? What I want is a two dividers: one with a 200px wide and another with 500px with a 5px top margin placed at the center of the page. See the image for more info.

```
<section>
<article>
<p>texttext text </p>
<div id="divider">
<div id="divider-short"> </div>
<div id="divider-long"> </div>
</div>
</article>
</section>

    #divider{
float:right;
margin-right:35%
direction:rtl;
}
#divider-short{
width:150px;
border:2px solid gray;
margin-top:30px;
clear:both;
}
#divider-long{
margin-top:10px;
width:300px;
border:2px solid gray;
clear:both;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you draw how you want it to look like? Or add a code snippet with working CSS for the divider?

Comment: I have attached a pic for more information to visualize what i am trying to achieve

Comment: "*2px solid at the center of page after a section or paragraph.*" - after the `<section>`, the `<paragraph>` or both? Please be clear about what you want, as it makes it easier to answer the question without having to guess.

Comment: Hi David sorry that my question was not clear. I wanted one common class as Prakash has advised below and use that whenever I needed a divider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create one common divider class and add it where you want divider.

```css
.divider{
  padding-bottom:25px;
  position:relative;
}
.divider:before,.divider:after{
  width:300px;
  height:2px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:8px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  
}
.divider:before{
  width:200px;
  bottom:14px;
}
```

```html
<section class="divider">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>
<section class="divider">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>
<section >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the divider HTML and use this CSS (adjust colors, spacing, etc):

```
article {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
article:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
article:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I learnt from your answer a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `<hr/>` tag that is dedicated for a breaker.
For example you can do the following to do two line break of multiple length

```
<hr style='width:25%'/>
<hr style='width:60%'/>
```

This is just an example, you can stylize hr the same way as other tags

Comment: Thanks Jaay. I did not know <hr> tag cool. i learnt that now